# Ember Data: Proper Way to Use findAll

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to use ember-data using https://github.com/emberjs/data as a reference.

Specifically, I am trying to use an array controller to display all of the 'Person' objects in my database. I also want to allow the user to create a new 'Person'.

I have the following code which works:

```
App.peopleController  = Em.ArrayController.create
  content: App.store.findAll(App.Person)

  newPerson: (name) ->
    App.store.create App.Person,
      name: name
    @set('content', App.store.findAll(App.Annotation))
```

However, it seems inefficient to reset the content property every time a new person is created. If I remove the last line and change the code to the following:

```
App.peopleController  = Em.ArrayController.create
  content: App.store.findAll(App.Person)

  newPerson: (name) ->
    App.store.create App.Person,
      name: name
```

A new view is still created on ever newPerson call, but the same object is duplicated. Essentially what is happening is all of the new templates use the first object created instead of a new one each time. I think this is related to the following bug: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/11.

For reference, my template logic is as follows:

```
{{#each App.peopleController}}
  {{#view App.PersonView contentBinding="this"}}
    {{#with content}}
      Client id is {{clientId}}
    {{/with}}
  {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

When I use the second version of my code-- the one with the `@set('content', App.store.findAll(App.Annotation))` line-- the clientId is duplicated for every Person object. In the first version, the client ids are correct.

Can anyone shed some light here? Am I doing this correctly? My instincts are telling me this is a bug but I am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is a bug. I posted a [related issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/17) that illustrates this issue.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully this gets fixed soon.

Comment: Was a bug. Came up with a fix and submitted a pull request for this issue: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/11.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `#collection` view instead.

See code of ToDo example.  Also see http://guides.sproutcore20.com/using_handlebars.html section 5 for some documentation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this just in case, but it still doesn't work and has the same problems. From my understanding, `#collection` is just shorthand for `#each` followed by a creation of a view for each element in the underlying collection.